# Link Only Format of One Cell in a range to Other cell in other range

Tags: excel, vba

I've an excel sheet consisting 2 Ranges (Same size) like shown in picture. [Sample Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvu4d.png). Now I want to link formatting of each cell in upper range to each corresponding cell in lower range. I've tried paste as linked image option but thats not useful as per my needs. 
So far, I've found following vba code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Clr

Clr = Me.Range("A1").Interior.Color
Me.Range("A5").Interior.Color = Clr
End Sub
```

Which is OK when using for a single cell. But when I modified it to whole range as following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Clr

    Clr = Me.Range("A1:B3").Interior.Color
    Me.Range("A5:B7").Interior.Color = Clr
End Sub
```

It no longer works properly. Please Help me on this. Any modification / new methods will be highly appreciated. Also don't wanna use loops as it is only a sample sheet and my actual sheet is much bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to simplify my answer quite significantly because I don't know how you want to apply it, but, I'd do this by copying and then paste special formats.

```
Public Sub CopyPasteSpecialFormats()
    Range("rngSrcData").Copy
    Range("rngFirstCellToCopyTo").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Throw the above code in a module or a change method or some way you want to call it.

[image: Example]

In the image above, I've created a named range called **rngSrcData** on cells **A1:E5**.  I also created a named range on the top left hand cell that represents the destination for the paste special operation.  The name of that range is **rngFirstCellToCopyTo** and in the image shown, it's defined at cell **A7**.

I then run the macro and it duplicates the formatting of the cells.

Working with named ranges can be dynamic as long as you insert within the range or make sure to update the named range if it extends beyond it's existing boundaries.

Alternatively, you can write some VBA to find the matrix you want to copy from.  The best part about the destination is that it's only ever the top left hand cell you need to worry about so you shouldn't need to think too hard about that.

As I originally said, I made the solution quite simple.  If you want to enforce the cell formatting each time the worksheet changes, this too will work ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("rngSrcData").Copy
    Range("rngFirstCellToCopyTo").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Target.Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

... it's a little bit clunky but does the job.  You also need to factor in though, all of your standard "undo" functionality will then be null and void.  It's something you need to consider.

Updating the individual cell that changed is also possible but you'd need more logic to determine an offset for the cell that changed.  Also, the changed event doesn't fire for everything, it only fires for cell data changes, not format changes.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Dear Brad Dixon, Thanks for quick response. Thats a great solution but I've to run the macro manually. Also I have hundreds of cells in my sheet and it will take time every time it runs. I'm looking for a solution that will catch the changed cell and will update the formatting of corresponding linked cell.

Comment: @MOwais yeah, it can be modified, hence why I said I’ve simplified my response. Let me update my answer with another option.

Comment: @MOwais what I’ve added may not be an individual cell update but it will catch all and regardless, I would think the amount of time it takes to process will be fairly unnoticeable compared to an individual cell approach. Let me know how well it works.

Comment: If it’s still not enough and it’s performing badly, let me know and I can take it to the next level. Of course, would prefer not to though. :-)